# How can I get rid of onclick in my js code, any alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I execute the following js function inside js instead of using a button with it? Also, can it be achieved without jQuery?

The function is `myFunction()`

The button is:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle dark mode</button>
```

The full code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Dark/Light Mode</h2>
<p>Click the button to toggle between dark and light mode for this page.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle dark mode</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, instead of using a button, use a span with a css `pointer` settle.

So basically I'm trying to achieve something like this:

HTML:

```
<span id="mybutton">Toggle nightmode</span>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    function myFunction.getElementbyID(#mybutton).(click) {
       var element = document.body;
       element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    }
</script>
```

It's ok if you offer a solution in jQuery, but I prefer vanilla javascript.

Comment: Just get the Element like you normally do with JavaScript like `Element.onclick = function(){}`

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to achieve this, the shortest way would just be to do:

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').onclick = () => { /* CODE GOES HERE */ };
```

If your function is already defined somewhere, you can replace the lambda function (This `()=>{}` thingy) with the name of your function, leaving you with this:

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').onclick = myFunction;
```

However, all that does is set the `onlcick` property of your element programatically, rather than setting it inline. If you want your element to not have the `onclick` property at all, you need to set an event listener for that element. This can be done like so:

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', () => {
    /* CODE GOES HERE */
});
```

Once again, that lambda function can be swapped out for the name of your function if its already defined somewhere else.

tldr your script element should look like:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', () => {
        var element = document.body;
        element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `    document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', () => {
        var element = document.body;
        element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    });`
Is throwing an error.

Comment: Whats error is it throwing in particular? Did you swap out your button for a span like you described in your question, if you use `<span id="mybutton">Toggle nightmode</span>` as your "button" and `<script>document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', () => {var element =document.body;element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");});</script>` as your script, I believe it should work (at least from when I tested it).